# Output when a user enters string for an int variable

Tags: c++, input, user-input

I'm currently reading Stroustrup's book on C++. In the user input section, it has the following example -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout << "Please enter your first name and age:\n";
    string firstName = "???"; // "??? means don't know the name"

    int age = -1; // -1 means don't know the age

    cin >> firstName >> age;

    cout << "Hello " << firstName << " (age " << age << ")\n";
}
```

As per the book, we initialize the `age` variable so as to get a predictable value if the input fails. 
The example says that the input `22 Carlos` will produce an output of `Hello 22 (age -1)`.

I've typed in the same code in a text editor (Sublime Text), but when I run the code with the above input, I get an age of 0 (not -1). 
Here's the screenshot of the outputs I get - 
          [output image from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfPlu.png).
And, here's the version of the compiler that I'm using - 
[compiler-version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY47D.png).

Can anyone explain as to why I don't get -1 as the age output, as the book claims?

Comment: A better solution is to not rely on particular values being assigned for error handling. `operator>>` puts the stream into an error state if extraction fails. Check for THAT state instead, eg: `if (cin >> firstName >> age) { cout << "Hello " << firstName << " (age " << age << ")\n"; } else { cout << "Bad input\n"; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that both are correct if that version of the book is more than a few years old.

Prior to C++11, the default behaviour of `operator>>` extracting an integer was to [leave it unchanged](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) if the extraction fails.

In C++11, this behaviour was changed to store 0 into the integer when extraction fails.

I don't have knowledge of why the change was made, but my guess is that it prevents a common class of undefined behaviour from people leaving a variable uninitialized and then not checking that extraction succeeded before using the variable.

Unfortunately, the machinery behind formatted input is quite lengthy, but the condensed version is that the call ultimately boils down to [`num_get::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get), where this behaviour is specified.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1: For your interest, it's also possible to [attach a different facet](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qy1WfvWVViT69gfP) for formatted input to use instead, meaning you could specify whatever behaviour you want for failure.</sup>